# Design suggestion for an invoice application

Tags: c#, oop, design-principles

I am trying to make an invoice management system for our company. I am a little bit confused because of design principles. SOLID

Lets say that a class takes care of invoices: InvoiceProcessor

```
InvoiceProcessor ip=new InvoiceProcessor(DraftHTML);
ip.Customer=theCustomer;
ip.Order=theOrder;
ip.Prepare();
```

After this, which approach is better? And why?

A)

```
ip.SaveToFile(fileName);
ip.SendToCustomer();

ip.DBConnection=myActiveConnection;
ip.LoadFromDB(invoiceID);
ip.SaveToDB();
```

B)

```
SaveToFile(fileName,ip.GetHTML());
SendEmail(ip.Customer,ip.GetHTML());

ip.InvoiceInfo=LoadFromDB(invoiceID);
SaveToDB(ip.InvoiceInfo);
```

Comment: To me -- it makes more sense for the domain, InvoiceProcessor, to deal with things related to processing an invoice. Therefore, option B makes the most sense.

Comment: I see a lot of responsibilities (preparing/creating-an-invoice, loading, saving, sending-email) and only a single class - This breaks SOLID already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imho, both A) and B) break the `SRP` principle, although B) is less coupled.

I would approach this in another way:

1. Create a new type which represents an `Invoice`
2. Make `InvoiceProcessor` return an instance of `Invoice`
3. For each post processing step create a different type of action.

The code should look like this:

```
var ip = new InvoiceProcessor
{
    Customer = theCustomer,
    Order = theOrder
};
var invoice = ip.CreateInvoice();
// Post processing
HtmlPrinter.PrintInvoice(invoice, htmlFileName);
DataAccess.SaveInvoice(invoice);
MailService.SendInvoiceToCustomer(invoice, theCustomer.Email);
```

Answer (score 0):

B option is better because you can use your methods in various ways. If you choose your first suggestion, in the future if you want to write a code let's say for your dispatches, then you have to write same code again for dispatch part . That will cause a bad pattern in your code. You should avoid repetitive code as possible as you can.